# Ler/Gravar informações em arquivo .cds

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, arquivo

Peguei um projeto para desenvolver em C#, o projeto se baseia em ler informações de um arquivo `.txt` e gravar as informações em um arquivo `.cds` existente que é usado em um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi.

Procurei uma API que faça isso  para C# mas encontrei nenhuma.

Comment: Eu criaria uma aplicação COM out-of-process em Delphi e chamaria em c# para fazer as alterações. Até que seja descontinuada a aplicação em Delphi e os dados sejam inteiramente migrados para nova aplicação

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Escreva uma aplicação em Delphi que lê este `.cds` e mande gravar ele em XML. Aí você poderá ler com o .NET. Não tem forma melhor, ou mesmo outra forma de fazer isto.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637609/221800).

Comment: essa não é uma solução, preciso ler e gravar nele.

Comment: Então vai ter que criar um biblioteca que faça isto. Boa sorte!